# Sending Email in php from html form

Tags: php, email

I have created one web page in html form which contains only 3 fields name, email and message and one button.Second page of php for sending mail named status.php.but when i click on send mail button it does not redirect to status.php instead it downloads that page.why this is happening.Anybody can tell..
here is the code:

```
<form method="post" action="status.php">
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label for="name">Name (required)&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" />
      </li>
      <br /><li>
        <label for="email">Email Address (required)&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" />
      </li>
      <br /><li>
        <label for="message">Your Message&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
      </li>
      <br /><li>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email"/>
      </li>
    </ol>
</form>
```

PHP Code :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $to = 'jafar.nadaf@ajinkyatechnologies.com';
        $subject = 'Email Test';
    }
    $status = 'Name: ' .$_POST['name']. "\r\n\r\n";
    $status .= 'Email: ' .$_POST['email']. "\r\n\r\n";
    $status .= 'Message: ' .$_POST['message'];
    echo $status;
?>
```

Comment: You could try adding the onSubmit attribute to your form,  <form method="post" onSubmit=window.location='status.php' action="status.php">

Comment: You should execute file using Absolute path for eg. http://localhost/first.html if you are using  relative path eg.file:///var/www/html/first.html then file get downloaded

Comment: ^ yup. good catch. I have missed the 'download' word

Comment: ^^ haven't thought of that lol. if @WisdmLabs solution doesn't work.. Maybe your server does not support php?

Comment: what to do if I want to do this all on same page....

Comment: add your html on the php file... and submit on the same page.

Comment: @JafarAli In which server you are running the program...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do all functionality in same page and refer following:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $to = 'jafar.nadaf@ajinkyatechnologies.com';
            $subject = 'Email Test';
        }
        $status = 'Name: ' .$_POST['name']. "\r\n\r\n";
        $status .= 'Email: ' .$_POST['email']. "\r\n\r\n";
        $status .= 'Message: ' .$_POST['message'];
        echo $status;
    ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
      <ol>
          <li>
            <label for="name">Name (required)&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" />
          </li>
          <br /><li>
            <label for="email">Email Address (required)&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" />
          </li>
          <br /><li>
            <label for="message">Your Message&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
          </li>
          <br /><li>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email"/>
          </li>
        </ol>
    </form>
```

Comment: oops.. now you need to check your server if it supports php.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set up a server on your local machine, e.g. LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP) or XAMPP when running a windows machine and try running your script with

> http://localhost/path/to/your/script

Your file needs to be located in the 'htdocs' directory of your server (unless you did some more configuration and changed that path)